# How to Create This Layout in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, flowlayout

Hi i'd like to know how do we implement this layout in collectionview od we need to put images or resize cells i followed this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest but in this they are passing image size for item so is showing different size of items based on  image size but i like to fix the layout some this like this in image [image]

Any help Would be Appreiciated

Thanks In Advance

Comment: now suppose you have only 1 or 2 images then what kind of flow you set ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  if i have only two it should show only two and  cell size should be fixed  like half and half it should be divided and am not sure how to do it fixed  with two three layouts what is the correct procedure for doing this

Comment: you have to set collectionviewlayout delegates method for create view like this width some condition.

Comment: If you want this layout regardless of content, why not make a custom `UIView` with five `UIImageViews` positioned already in that layout?

Then if you need multiple sets of it just add that custom `UIView` to the cell of a `tableView`/`collectionView`.

Comment: @BenOng if i want two or three different layouts how should it will be get done

Comment: That will change a little, you might want to create prototype cells in a `tableView`/`collectionView` with one of each layout you have, then reuse each of them depending on which you want. If there is even more than 3-4 layouts, I suggest you wait/look at the answers providing codes/libraries to help you layout your views.

Comment: @BenOng ok Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dynamic-height-for-collectionview) awesome control to achieve your goal.

It is very simple to use.

**Add Following Files to your project**

```
customLayout.h
customLayout.m
```

**Import customLayout in your controller where to use**

```
#import "customLayout.h"
```

And use

```
<customLayoutDelegate>
```

to your controller.

**Write Simple Code in your viewDidLoad Method**

```
 columncount=2; // How much Columns you required
    miniInteriorSpacing=10; // Minimum Spacing you required

    if(![collectionView.collectionViewLayout isKindOfClass:[customLayout class]]){
        customLayout *layout = [customLayout new];
        layout.delegate=self;
        layout.columnCount=columncount;

        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;

        [collectionView reloadData];
    }
```

**For getting height of Label I have written a method.**

```
-(float)calculateHeightForLbl:(NSString*)text width:(float)width;
```

Comment: i  have  to load diffent cells like for  2 images one layout and for 4 images one layout and for 6 images one layout how to achive it dynamically do i need to do with xibs

Comment: YES, you will have to create separate xib for your requirement.